# Angular 5 replace initial formControlName with reference value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and it first initializes with an object , and as its being or been built(Dont know what happens) I make some calculations on the fly and change the input of the some of the input values with reference variable values, but then I realise when I submit the form, the reference variable values dont replace the value of the formControlName hence the value of the object. Unless I manually re insert the value then it works. What I dont understand is the input fields shows the right reference variable values. But when submitted the values are not changed in the object, the old initialization values still shows. Pls help.

```
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td><input formControlName="productName" type="text" readonly></td>
        <td><input formControlName="unitPrice" type="number" readonly></td>
        <td><input #amount formControlName="quantity" type="number" [readonly]="true"></td>
        <td><input formControlName="deliveryStatusIdSellingPrice" type="number"></td>
        <td><input #amountDelivered formControlName="deliveryStatusAmountDelivered" type="number" min="0" max="{{amount.value}}"></td>
        <td><input formControlName="remainingAmountToDeliver" type="number" value="{{amount.value - amountDelivered.value}}" min="0"></td>
        <td><input #defectedAmount formControlName="deliveryStatusDefectedAmount" type="number"></td>
        <td><input #undefectedAmount formControlName="deliveryStatusUndefectedAmount" type="number" value="{{amountDelivered.value - defectedAmount.value}}" readonly></td>
        <td><input formControlName="restockedAmount" type="number" readonly></td>
        <td><input formControlName="deliveryStatusAmountToRestock" type="number" value="{{undefectedAmount.value}}"></td>
        <td><input formControlName="deliveryStatusDeliveredDate" type="date"></td>
        <td>
```

So basically the formControlNames (remainingAmountToDeliver ,deliveryStatusUndefectedAmount and deliveryStatusAmountToRestock) are the problems now. Thank you

Comment: Why are the calculated values inputs? You just want to set these as initial values, or you want to submit the values calculated from `amount`, etc.? If the latter then there's not really any reason for them to be inputs.

Comment: I am using an object so the object initial values are suppose to filled in the inputs but I override some of them with my calculations , and the calculated values appear in the input fields as the new values but now when I submit it is not being set in the object values. I hope you understand my point. I wan to set them as well with the reference values. But when i manually change the field and lets say I retype the calculated value, and submit it works fine

Comment: Why do you want to manually change calculated fields?

Comment: I am saying when I manually change it , i.e the moment I write in the field the object value connected with the formControlName changes but when the form loads the fields are populated automatically with the calculated reference values they do not change also in the object value connected by the formControlName. So I dont want to manually change the calculated vales. But as at now it only works when I touch the input field and that is the problem I am complaining about